# Can champions be effective warriors?

Tags: fallen-enchantress

Champions in Fallen Enchantress are like RPGs writ small: they level up, gain traits, can be equipped with varying equipment, and are the only units that can complete quests and pick up equipment.

The trouble is I can't figure out how to make effective warrior-champions. When I equip a champion with a sword, he's less effective than a unit of three grunts wielding the same sword: to wit, he has about the same attack as *just one* of those grunts. He may live a bit longer, but he's usually doing pretty terrible damage unless I've gotten lucky and found an excellent weapon. Otherwise, if I buy him equipment from the shop (i.e., the same equipment I can equip my regular units with), he ends up being a very expensive copy of a single figure of a unit, because the shop practices daylight robbery.  The unit that I would otherwise build with the same equipment will be cheaper, do more damage (three guys with the same weapon!), and have about the same number of hit points (3 weak guys roughly equals one low-level champion; it only gets worse once I can have 4, 5, or 6 guys in a unit).

Champions make fine mages, doubly so since **only** champions can be mages. **But how do I make a non-mage champion effective?**

Comment: One small advantage I ran into was that your champion can also buy from shops from other players, so you can get better weapons for him if other empires are more advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Champions are very weak as late game warriors. It's a common problem of Fallen Enchantress.

Developer are trying to address it in the expansion (Legendary Heroes), which is currently in beta.

You can see ongoing discussions on that matter here: http://forums.elementalgame.com/444392 and on that forum itself.

Comment: I've had problems with champions as *early* game warriors. They're a bit better than Militia, Spearmen, and other *very* early units, and even moreso if you've gotten lucky on a quest and picked up a great weapon, but that's what makes a "decent" warrior champion - luck.

Comment: @PaulMarshall wow, you accepted answer after 4 years! :)

Comment: I was desperately hoping there was a better answer for a while, and then I forgot about this question. And now, at long last, I trawled through my old questions and saw this. Hooray for multiple Yearling badges!